# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Psycopg2 has been giving me this error whenever I try to update a row:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p:/Projects/Freelance/Optometry_Inventory/code/tester.py", line 39, in <module>
    new_user.updateUser(*(fname, lname, username, role, hashed_pwd, user_id))
  File "p:\Projects\Freelance\Optometry_Inventory\code\UserDC.py", line 64, in updateUser
    cursor.execute(update_query, args)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "lname"
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET fname= ('a'), SET lname= ('b'),
```

When I run the following function:

```
def updateUser(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        update_query = """UPDATE users SET fname= %s, SET lname= (%s),
         SET username= (%s), SET user_role= (%s), SET h_pwd= (%s), WHERE user_id= (%s)"""
        with pool() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(update_query, (self.fname, self.lname, self.user_name,
                           self.user_role, self.user_pwd, self.user_id))
```

I have tried just updating a single field and I still get the same error. Is there something more I am missing? The error code isn't giving me much information.

Comment: You only need one `SET` at the beginning and you have to remove the comma before the `WHERE`. And you can get rid of the parentheses in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you redundantly write `SET` for every modified column, one `SET` is more than enough :)

```py
def updateUser(self, user_id):
    self.user_id = user_id
    update_query = """
        UPDATE users 
        SET fname= %s, 
            lname= (%s),
            username= (%s), 
            user_role= (%s),
            h_pwd= (%s) 
        WHERE user_id= (%s)"""
        with pool() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(update_query, (self.fname, self.lname, self.user_name,
                           self.user_role, self.user_pwd, self.user_id))
```

Comment: @le-travie let me know if this works fine

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you, I realized I had way too many sets #facepalm

Comment: Unfortunately my rep isn't high enough to mark this as the answer. If someone else see it I hope they do.

Comment: hehe yeah that happens

Comment: @le_travie and now you can :)

Comment: @le_travie hehe no worries at all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save yourself some typing there is also:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = con.cursor()
update_query = """
        UPDATE users 
        SET 
         (fname, lname, username,user_role, h_pwd)
          =
         (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        WHERE user_id= (%s)"""
cursor.execute(update_query, (self.fname, self.lname, self.user_name,
                           self.user_role, self.user_pwd, self.user_id))
```

If you are doing multiple updates at a time you might also want to take a look at [execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers). There is an `UPDATE` example in the execute_values section of the link.